# Why are my caption and subtitle not appearing in the viewer tab, but appear in the plot tab?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

My caption and subtitle appear in the plot tab, but not the viewer tab. The interactive part of my plot also only works in the viewer tab, and not the plot tab! I am not sure why this is (first piece of data visualisation I have done.

I have not found a solution - does anyone know?

```
df_select %>%
ggplot(aes(x = monthlyDateN,
           y = CivilAviationTotalPassengerKm_million_passengerkilometres_monthly_average_or_calendar_months,
           colour = country.name.en,
           group = country.name.en,
           text = paste("Country: ", country.name.en, "<br>",
                        "Date: ", monthlyDateN, "<br>",
                        "Total km (millions): ", CivilAviationTotalPassengerKm_million_passengerkilometres_monthly_average_or_calendar_months, "<br>",
                        "Population: ", pop, "<br>"))) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 0.5) +
  geom_point(size = 0.1) +
  labs(x = "Date",
       y = "Total Civil (Passenger) Aviation in km Million",
       title = "Total Civil Aviation Per Calendar Month",
       subtitle = "European Countries in 2020 & 2021",
       caption = "Source: https://unstats.un.org/unsd/mbs/app/DataSearchSeries.aspx",
       colour = "Country",) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15000), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  dark_mode(theme_bw()) 
ggplotly(tooltip = c("text"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a subtitle to your plotly chart you can remove `title = "Total Civil Aviation Per Calendar Month"`,
`subtitle = "European Countries in 2020 & 2021"` and `caption = "Source: https://unstats.un.org/unsd/mbs/app/DataSearchSeries.aspx"` from `labs` and do

```
  ggplotly() %>% 
    plotly::layout(title = list(text = paste0("Total Civil Aviation Per Calendar Month",
                                             "<br>",
                                             "European Countries in 2020 & 2021")),
                   annotations = list(x = 1, y = -0.1, 
                                      text = "Source: https://unstats.un.org/unsd/mbs/app/DataSearchSeries.aspx", 
                                      showarrow = F, xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper', 
                                      xanchor = 'auto', yanchor = 'auto', xshift = 0, yshift = 0,
                                      font = list(size = 15)))
```